# rx disposes subscription on exception if has linq methods in the middle

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

When I subscribe with a method which sometimes throws an exception, I get 2 different acts.
If I concatenate LINQ methods in the middle, the subscription is disposed, other wise it is not, why?

```
void main(){
  var numbersSubject=new Subject<int>();

  numbersSubject.subscribe(throwMethod);   // 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10
  // numbersSubject.select(num=>num).subscribe(throwMethod);   // 1,2,3,4

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    try{
      numbersSubject.OnNext(i);
    }catch{}
  }
}

void throwMethod(int num)
{
   if(num==5)
       throw new Exception();
   Console.writeLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, to clarify:

When the version **without** the LINQ operator is run we see:

```
0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9
```

When the version **with** the LINQ operator is run we see:

```
0,1,2,3,4
```

Notably, when you subscribe a good and a bad behaving Observer to the second version you get output as shown below (output in the comments) like so:

```
numbersSubject.Subscribe(throwMethod);   
var source = numbersSubject.Select(num=>num);
source.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine); // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
source.Subscribe(throwMethod);   // 0,1,2,3,4
```

Notice that the "good" Observer gets all events.

The reason is that the build in operators have a protective layer that disposes the *subscription* of a bad Observer.

From the Rx source code we see:

Safeguarding of the pipeline against rogue observers is required for proper resource clean-up. Consider the following example:

```
var xs  = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var ys  = <some random sequence>;
var res = xs.CombineLatest(ys, (x, y) => x + y);
```

The marble diagram of the query above looks as follows:

```
xs  -----0-----1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6-----7-----8-----9---...
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
ys  --------4--+--5--+-----+--2--+--1--+-----+-----+--0--+-----+---...
            |  |  |  |     |  |  |  |  |     |     |  |  |     |
            v  v  v  v     v  v  v  v  v     v     v  v  v     v
res --------4--5--6--7-----8--5--6--5--6-----7-----8--7--8-----9---...
                              |
                             @#&
```

Notice the free-threaded nature of Rx, where messages on the resulting sequence are produced by either of the two input sequences to `CombineLatest`.

Now assume an exception happens in the `OnNext` callback for the observer of `res`, at the indicated point marked with `@#&` above. The callback runs in the context of `ys`, so the exception will take down the scheduler thread of `ys`. This by itself is a problem (that can be mitigated by a `Catch` operator on `IScheduler`), but notice how the timer that produces `xs` is kept alive.

The safe-guarding code ensures the acquired resources are disposed when the user callback throws.

---

The above is implemented in an internal class called `AutoDetachObserver` and wrapped by `SafeObserver` used by most of the internal operators.

All this does is wrap each OnXXX invocation with `try...finally` Exception handlers whose finally block disposes the subscription in the event of an error - e.g. `OnNext` looks like:

```
        var __noError = false;
        try
        {
            observer.OnNext(value);
            __noError = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!__noError)
                Dispose();
        }
```

`Subject`, for performance reasons, doesn't have this layer of protection. A quick way of adding it (and protecting against other abuses) is to add the `Synchronize()` operator to the subject. e.g:

```
var numbersSubject = new Subject<int>();
var source = numbersSubject.Synchronize();
source.Subscribe(throwMethod);
```

Will output

```
0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9
```

But adding `Synchronize` as shown:

```
var numbersSubject = new Subject<int>();
var source = numbersSubject.Synchronize();
source.Synchronize().Subscribe(throwMethod);
```

Will output

```
0,1,2,3,4
```

consistent with the other built-in operators (plus any you implement with `Observable.Create`).

#### (EDIT) Notes on handling observer exceptions

Prompted by the comments, here are some additional notes on handling of exceptions thrown from observers.

When an exception originates in the OnNext handler, it's *below* the Rx code in the stack and it's therefore not possible to responsibly pass it "back" to the user. The user has to be considered dead at that point. All we can reasonably do is dispose the subscription and clean up the resources due to it. This is the consequence of push-based code. Contrast with IEnumerable where exceptions can be thrown to the client code, because it's the client doing the pulling.

Note that certain operators contain user-provided logic (like the predicate expression in a `Where` operator) that *will* propagate errors through the `OnError` channel to an observer, but once an observer has died by throwing an exception in it's own code - that's it. It won't be called via any `OnXXX` methods again.

There's a ton more on this starting about half way down [this epic Bart de Smet post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/17/reactive-extensions-v2-0-release-candidate-available-now.aspx).

Comment: Thank for the answer. The results indeed were reversed, my mistake (fixed the question)

Comment: Fixed my answer to reflect that fact you fixed your question. :)

Comment: Again, thanks for the detailed answer.
I have some questions regarding it:
1. Why did you write that the context is ys? the event (of number 4) is raised in the xs stream.
2. Why does the exception take down the thread and not thrown up the stack until the onNext of the user?

Comment: Hi ie1 - DOH! I made a mistake in my copy/pasting of the diagram, well spotted! :) Should make more sense now! Let me know if that resolves your outstanding questions. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Hi, I would be happy if you could refer also to the second question

Comment: Edited my comments into the question.